# Would this be the correct syntax for Swift 1.2?

Tags: swift

I have seen this method:

```
func sum(x:Int, y: Int) -> Int {
   return x+y
}
```

would I need to call this via:

```
let x1 = sum(4, y:11)
```

because this doesn't seem to work:

```
let x1 = sum(4, 11)
```

Comment: Why do you name a Method sum and returns the result of a multiplication?

Comment: lol - just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method, `y` is labelled as `y` both internally and externally. Therefore, to call the method, you must name the parameter. If you want to call the sum method the way you're describing, add an underscore before `y` like so:

```
func sum(x:Int, _ y: Int) -> Int {
    var j = x*y
    return j
}
```

Comment: was that different between 1.1 and 1.2? is y being auto-externalized? thx

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't believe there was ever a difference though as named parameters have always been a thing in Swift. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Or, better yet, force the naming of the first parameter by using #. A simple sum function is perhaps a bad example, but continuing the Objective-C legacy of named parameters is a good thing, IMO.

Comment: I definitely agree. Named parameters should be used as much as possible. However, for a sum function, the inputs are definitely implied.

Comment: thx Aaron - was surprised because I saw this in a book; don't fully get all the downvotes but alas....